# mencoder and 2 webcams

Tags: record, mencoder

If I want to record a video from a webcam. I use the following command:

```
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=320:height=240:device=/dev/video0 -ovc lavc -o webcam.avi
```

But, I want make a record from 2 webcams simultaneously (`/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`). How?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

```
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=320:height=240:device=/dev/video0 -ovc lavc -o webcam.avi &
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=320:height=240:device=/dev/video1 -ovc lavc -o webcam2.avi
```